# Use list P to display list L's values

Tags: java, linked-list

This is a simple HW question and the following was my code:

**You are given a list, L, and another list, P, containing integers sorted in ascending order. The operation printLots(L,P) will print the elements in L that are in positions specified by P. For instance, if P = 1, 3, 4, 6, the elements in positions 1, 3, 4, and 6 in L are printed. Write the procedure printLots(L,P). You may use only the public Collections API container operations**

**My code:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Lists {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        LinkedList<Integer> L = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> P = new LinkedList<Integer>();



        L.addAll(Arrays.asList(4,9,13,50,65,87,91,99));

        P.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,3,4,6));


        int sample=L.indexOf(P);


        System.out.println(L);
        System.out.println(P);
        System.out.println(sample);

    }
}
```

OutPut:

```
[4, 9, 13, 50, 65, 87, 91, 99]

[1, 3, 4, 6]

-1
```

I'm confused with several things...if i'm working with LinkedLists why involve arrays into the code?

Also how can I displays the values of L for the corresponding P positions? :)

Answer (score 2):

What is the use of this line i am not getting

```
int sample=L.indexOf(P);
```

try this instead of your that line

```
int sample=P.size();
for(int i=0;i<sample;i++){
    System.out.println(L.get(P.get(i)));
}
```

Output

```
9 50 65 91
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer>L = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4,9,13,50,65,87,91,99));
ArrayList<Integer>P = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,3,4,6));

for(Integer current: P){
    System.out.print(L.get(current)+" ");
}
```

Output: 9 50 65 91

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] L = {1, 3, 4, 6};
    int[] P = {5, 7, 2, 1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 8};

    for(int e : L) {
        System.out.println(P[e]);
    }
```

Output: 7 1 5 3